# Building PX4 source code along with Gazebo on Ubuntu 18.04 failed

Tags: opencv, ros, gazebo-simu, px4

I am working on building PX4 source code along with Gazebo 9 on Ubuntu 18.04. I am following the PX4 tutorial from this link:
https://docs.px4.io/v1.12/en/simulation/gazebo.html

These are the steps I did:

1. I downloaded PX4 source code (succeeded):

```
         $git clone https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot.git --recursive
         $bash ./PX4-Autopilot/Tools/setup/ubuntu.sh
         $reboot
```

2. I downloaded ROS Melodic (succeeded):

   ```
        #Note: ROS 1 full desktop builds come with Gazebo Classic)
   ```

```
         $wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PX4/Devguide/master/build_scripts/ubuntu_sim_ros_melodic.sh
         $bash ubuntu_sim_ros_melodic.sh
```

3. Running the simulation (*Here is my problem*):

   ```
        #Note: Run a simulation by starting PX4 SITL and gazebo with the airframe configuration to load the Quad frame.

        #Running with cmake version 3.10.2
   ```

```
         $cd /path/to/PX4-Autopilot
         $**make px4_sitl gazebo  #failed**
```

Making the px4_sitl with gazebo gives this error :

```
FAILED: CMakeFiles/gazebo_aruco_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp.o
```

and here are some log messages for warnings and error of making the px4_sitl gazebo command:

```
/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:44:0,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:42,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/include/opencv2/aruco/dictionary.hpp:61:20: error: redefinition of ‘class cv::aruco::Dictionary’
 class CV_EXPORTS_W Dictionary {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp:7:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:874,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:80,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:40,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_dictionary.hpp:25:27: note: previous definition of ‘class cv::aruco::Dictionary’
 class CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE Dictionary {
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:44:0,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:42,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/include/opencv2/aruco/dictionary.hpp:142:19: error: redeclaration of ‘DICT_4X4_50’
     DICT_4X4_50 = 0,
                   ^
```

```
/usr/include/opencv2/aruco/dictionary.hpp:158:5: error: redeclaration of ‘DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL’
     DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp:7:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:874,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:80,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:40,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_dictionary.hpp:109:5: note: previous declaration ‘cv::aruco::PredefinedDictionaryType DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL’
     DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL,    ///< 6x6 bits, minimum hamming distance between any two codes = 3, 1024 codes
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:44:0,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:42,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/include/opencv2/aruco/dictionary.hpp:171:30: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(int)’
 CV_EXPORTS_W Ptr<Dictionary> getPredefinedDictionary(int dict);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp:7:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:874,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:80,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:40,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_dictionary.hpp:124:25: note: old declaration ‘cv::aruco::Dictionary cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(int)’
 CV_EXPORTS_W Dictionary getPredefinedDictionary(int dict);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:42:0,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/include/opencv2/aruco.hpp:124:21: error: redefinition of ‘struct cv::aruco::DetectorParameters’
 struct CV_EXPORTS_W DetectorParameters {
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect.hpp:874:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:80,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/include/gazebo_aruco_plugin.h:40,
                 from /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/simulation/gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic/src/gazebo_aruco_plugin.cpp:31:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/objdetect/aruco_detector.hpp:346:19: note: previous specification in ‘void cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(cv::InputOutputArray, cv::InputArrayOfArrays, cv::InputArray, cv::Scalar)’ here
 CV_EXPORTS_W void drawDetectedMarkers(InputOutputArray image, InputArrayOfArrays corners,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-address-of-packed-member’
[120/142] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/gazebo_gst_camera_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_gst_camera_plugin.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[945/949] Linking CXX executable bin/px4
FAILED: external/Stamp/sitl_gazebo-classic/sitl_gazebo-classic-build 
cd /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo-classic && /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/kjarrah/workspace/Jarrah_thesis/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo-classic -- -j 3
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Makefile:232: recipe for target 'px4_sitl' failed
make: *** [px4_sitl] Error 1
```

I do appreciate helping me what dependencies are  missing to fix this issue.